# AWS - Amazon Workspaces & AWS boto3 cannot run script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, windows-server-2016, amazon-workspaces

I get an error when trying to execute a boto3 (python3) script in Amazon Workspaces (Windows Server) at work. Here are the script and steps.

Environment: Windows Server Datacenter

Script:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object)
```

Steps:

- install boto3
- Run the python script using python your_script.py
- Get the following error

**"botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: check_hostname requires server_hostname"**

I can execute AWS CLI commands in the workspace with no issues e.g. `aws s3` commands all work properly. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Proxy related perhaps. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=337672

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the issue

Replace

`s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`

with

`s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(proxies={'https':'your_proxy_server_ip:3128'})})`